# When are preferences saved to file?

Tags: android, preference, edittextpreference

I have a EditTextPreference and I don't know when that string get saved to the Shared Preferences file.

If I start with a null string, and change it to "Hello", when does this update get saved?  Do I have to save it manually?

Comment: Give the correct answer to Joel instead of me, as Geobits pointed out ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a EditTextPreference and don't know when it commits that string
>   to the Shared Preferences file

If you take a look at the [EditTextPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html) documentation, the text gets saved upon calling the `setText(String)` method.  This method commits saves the text to the SharedPreferences.  The preferences will never be updated until you call that method.  For example...

```
EditTextPreference mPrefs = ...

//perform any manipulations on the string, not saved until you call setText()
String mText = "2";
mText += " + 2";
mText += " = 4";

// saves "2 + 2 = 4" to SharedPreferences
mPrefs.setText(mText);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you commit it, by calling either `Editor.commit()` or `Editor.apply()`.

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html)

Comment: This is plain wrong. This applies to using `SharedPreferences.Editor`, but has nothing to do with an `EditTextPreference`. Joel's answer is correct; when you call `setText()`, it saves to `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: You're right - sorry, I don't know how I could miss that part of the question - guess I was a bit quick to answer - give the right answer to Joel ;-)
However "behind the scenes", the `Editor.commit()` is called when you call `setText(text)` ;-)

Comment: That's true! Behind the scenes, these calls are being made.  However, that is a bit beyond the scope of his question

Comment: @Joel yeah I know, that's why the credit for the correct answer should go to you ofc ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source for [EditTextPreference.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/preference/EditTextPreference.java), the String is persisted in the setText() method.

So, it'll be committed to the SharedPreferences file after the text is changed.

Answer (score 0):

when u edit your prefrence you may use the following code:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);


Editor edit = sp.edit();
edit.putString("Preference_Label", variable_name);
edit.commit(); // this commits the edit
```